# Different results from executing a stored procedure using exec sp_executesql compared to EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a table in the database which consists of some postcodes with their latitude and longitude for example:

```
Id  PostCode    Latitude         Longitude
1   ll29 8ht    53.2973289489746    -3.72970223426819
```

The table is generated by MVC code-first application,
Latitude and longitude data type is real

I have a stored procedure that takes as input searchLatitude and searchLongitude and then calculates the distances:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StockistSearch] 
    @searchLat float = 0,
    @searchLng float = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT top 40 
s.Id as Id,
a.Company as Company,
a.FirstName as FirstName,
a.LastName as LastName,
a.Address1 as Address1,
a.Address2 as Address2,
a.City as City,
a.ZipPostalCode as ZipPostalCode,
a.PhoneNumber as PhoneNumber,
a.FaxNumber as FaxNumber,
a.Email as Email,
s.latitude as Latitude,
s.longitude as Longitude,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@searchLat) )
* cos( radians( s.latitude ) )
* cos( radians( s.longitude )
- radians(@searchLng) )
+ sin( radians(@searchLat) )
* sin( radians( s.latitude ) ) ) )
AS Distance
FROM Stockist s, Customer c, Address a
where s.CustomerId = c.Id
and c.ShippingAddress_Id = a.Id     
ORDER BY distance
END
```

If I execute this through SQL server management studio, it executes the following:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[StockistSearch]
    @searchLat = 53.29,
    @searchLng = -3.72

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Which return the distance correctly (0.645 miles)

However, when executed through the application using :

```
var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(commandText, parameters).ToList();
```

which according to a trace, executes:

```
exec sp_executesql N'StockistSearch',N'@searchLat float,@searchLng float',@searchLat=53.29,@searchLng=-3.72
```

which results in a completely different (and wrong) result for the calculated distance, (it returns distance 3688.96 miles!)

I've stepped through the code in debug and the parameters are being entered correctly and have confirmed that the exec sp_executesql is giving a different result that the EXEC when ran directly in the SQL server management studio

I'm completely at a loss as to why this is happening and although the stored procedure seems to be functioning correctly, the results showing through the application are completely wrong.

Please can someone please give me some advice before I go mad!!

Thanks

## UPDATE

Thanks for all the comments so far and thanks to @McKay, I've narrowed it down to it ignoring the input parameters when called from exec sp_executesql and is using the defaults 0 for both latitude and longitude. If i remove the defaults, I get the error:

```
Procedure or function 'StockistSearch' expects parameter '@searchLat', which was not supplied.
```

The SQL query is

```
exec sp_executesql N'StockistSearch', N'@searchLat real, @searchLng real',@searchLat=53.29,@searchLng=-3.72
```

This sql is automatically generate by the entity framework (code-first MVC EF doesn't currently support stored procedures but should be able to query stored procedures using the following in the DbContext:)

```
var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(commandText, parameters).ToList();
```

Would greatly appreciate any further help

## FIXED :-)

When calling :

```
var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(commandText, parameters).ToList();
```

The command text has to have the parameters appended to it so

```
commandText = "StockistSearch @searchLat,@searchLng"
```

so the resulting sql is;

```
exec sp_executesql N'StockistSearch @searchLat,@searchLng', N'@searchLat real, @searchLng real',@searchLat=53.29,@searchLng=-3.72
```

It now accepts the input parameters and calculates the correct distance

Comment: Thanks for the speedy comments, the stored procedure is part of a larger stored procedure and i've tried to strip it down to the basics to the part that's not returning the correct values, hopefully typos resolved now

Comment: I've updated this with all the original code. Everything is working great apart from the calculated distance

Comment: You know SQL Server now has a `geography` data type, right? And you should join tables using `join`, not `where`

Comment: Is the ID of the returned result the same in both instances?

Comment: There's probably just something confused, like a connection to the wrong procedure, database or server. Or connection options like ANSI_NULLS although they do not play a role in the code you posted.

Comment: @podiluska, yes the id is the same, there's currently only one field in the table, the database and the table is generated by code-first MVC. Thanks for your comment but i don't see how it relates to the difference in the value for distance depending on how the stored proc is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers that are this different make me think that maybe it's using the default values for something? Have you taken out the defaults?

Maybe you could also add the parameters to the select, to make sure you get what you're expecting.

```
SELECT top 40 
    @searchLatitude,
    @searchLongitude,
    l.Id as Id,
    l.Postcode as Postcode,
    l.latitude as Latitude,
    l.longitude as Longitude,
```

This might aid in your debugging process.

Comment: Hi McKay, your right about it using the default values, I manually executed using 0 and 0 as the latitude and longitude and it gave me the 3688 mile result.

Comment: However if I remove the defaults, the app is now giving me the error:Procedure or function 'StockistSearch' expects parameter '@searchLat', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two stored procedures, one called DistanceSearch and one called StockistSearch? It looks that way from your code. Are you sure the correct procedure is being called?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like things are pretty different. Parameter names don't match up either.

Comment: hi, sorry, its another typo. its part of a larger stored procedure and i've stripped out part of it for testing and pasted the part of it that's not working

Comment: @samsinfield we'd probably need to see the rest of it then. There must be a mis-assignment somewhere :(

Comment: i've added the whole of the stored procedure now, its only the calculated distance that isn't working, everything is is working as expected

Comment: @samsinfield you're taking the return value of the procedure, which doesn't look like it's assigned to anything in your example? Also you're doing top 40 rows?

Comment: @Meff This is just the code that is executed by the sql server manager when the stored proc is executed in the manager which i've posted to demonstrate, the app is not taking the return value. its an MVC code-first app, yes, top 40 rows (sorted by distance), its for a 'nearest store locator based on distance. Its the distance value that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Error in your proc.

```
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(@searchLatitude) )
* cos( radians( l.latitude ) )
* cos( radians( l.longitude )
- radians(@searchLongitude) )
+ sin( radians(@searchLat) )
* sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) )
```

one uses @searchLat, one uses @searchLatitude

Wait, the proc seems to select tables, and not have a return value, but your execution is expecting an out parameter?

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, thats just a typo from when i've copied the code across :-(, it is actually correct in the actual stored procedure

Comment: @samsinfield You should probably update the example to make sure things are uniform. So we can actually help?

Comment: thanks @McKay, have updated the code now, let me know if i've missed anything else

Comment: @samsinfield I've updated my response. It still looks like you have differences between what we see wrt out parameters

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in how it's called.

Your SSMS call returns the return value.

Your `sp_executesql` call returns the dataset. I'm guessing the 40th closest stockist is 3688.96 miles away

Comment: Thanks for your comment but there there is no 40th stockist, just the one field in the database for testing. The exec sp_executesql isn't accepting the input parameters for some reason and is using the default (0 and 0) which would be 3688 miles away